# Line breaks in javascript return

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add line breaks to the response in this already working javascript:

```
if (/example text/i.test(text)) return "example response";
```

I've tried all of the following and none have worked:

```
if (/example text/i.test(text)) return "example response 1/nexample response 2";
if (/example text/i.test(text)) return "example response 1" + '/n' + "example response 2";
if (/example text/i.test(text)) return "example response 1<br />example response 2";
```

etc etc

Is there any easy way to accomplish this inline without adding vars or more complexity to the rest of my code?

Comment: A line break is `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: Where is this string going to be used ? As HTML ?

Comment: Argh, sorry that's what i meant.

Comment: @user2204323 I'm not sure I got your last comment. Did Felix's answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

If your string is going to be displayed as HTML, you may do this :

```
if (/example text/i.test(text))
    return "example response 1<br"+">example response 2";
```

Comment: Didn't work, maybe my code is rendering as straight plain text instead of as html?

    $('div').thedivclass(function(text){the if/return code above}, null, type);

Is this screwing up how it renders?

Comment: Well, what does do `thedivclass` ?

Comment: $('<p class=response>').appendTo(self),handler(this.textContent || this.innerText);

The code you suggested renders this if it helps: <p class="response"><span>example response 1&lt;br&gt;example response 2</span></p>

Comment: Ok, so it uses it as text. There is no direct solution, you'd better change your code so that it doesn't use `this.textContent || this.innerText` but `this.innerHTML`.

Comment: this.innerHTML as you directed worked, it's respecting html markup now, thx!